# C: Differences between strchr() and index()

Tags: c, string, standard-library

I am doing something in C which requires use of the strings (as most programs do).

Looking in the manpages, I found, at string(3):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <strings.h>
>
> char * index(const char *s, int c)
>
> (...)
>
> #include <string.h>
>
> char * strchr(const char *s, int c)
> ```

So I curiously looked at both strchr(3) and index(3)...

And I found that both do the following:

> The strchr()/index() function locates the first occurrence of c in the string
>   pointed to by s. The terminating null character is considered to be part of the
>   string; therefore if c is '\0', the functions locate the terminating '\0'.

So, the manpage is basically a copy & paste.

Besides, I suppose that, because of some obfuscated necessity, the second parameter has type `int`, but is, in fact, a `char`. I think I am not wrong, but can anyone explain to me why is it an `int`, not a `char`?

If they are both the same, which one is more compatible across versions, and if not, which's the difference?

Comment: FYI, here is a bit of history:
http://groups.google.com/group/net.micro.att/msg/4c277db8350decaa?hl=en

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`strchr()` is part of the C standard library.  `index()` is [a now deprecated POSIX function.](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/index.html)  The POSIX specification recommends implementing `index()` as a macro that expands to a call to `strchr()`.

Since `index()` is deprecated in POSIX and not part of the C standard library, you should use `strchr()`.

The second parameter is of type `int` because these functions predate function prototypes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5919802/ for more information on this.

Comment: index() is also `part of the C standard library` anyway. But you are both right.

Comment: @ssice:  No, it isn't.  The word "index" doesn't appear anywhere in the C standard library specification (clause 7 of C99).

Comment: @ssice: who says `index()` is part of the C standard library?

Comment: @ssice:  Your particular standard library implementation may have an `index()` function, but if it does it is a language extension.  `index()` is not part of the C standard library.

Comment: @ssice:  You get yourself a copy of the language standard (you can find out how from [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the index() function is an older one that should be replaced by strchr().
See http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/index.html where they suggest to replace index by strchr and mark index as a legacy function.