# Why does the function `memchr()` use `int` for the argument of `char` type?

Tags: c, char

The following function uses `int` as the second argument type,

```
memchr(const void *buf, int ch, size_t count);
```

Though it is used for a `character` type. Why is the function defined to use `int` for the argument of `char` type? Are there any special reasons for this?

Comment: You might also want to read this which is basically the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919735/why-does-memset-take-an-int-instead-of-a-char

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is so because this is a very "old" standard function, which existed from the very early times of C language evolution.

Old versions of C did not have such things as *function prototypes*. Functions were either left undeclared, or declared with "unknown" parameter list, e.g.

```
void *memchr(); /* non-prototype declaration */
```

When calling such functions, all argument were subjected to automatic *argument promotions*, which means that such functions never received argument values of type `char` or `short`. Such arguments were always implicitly promoted by the caller to type `int` and the function itself actually received an `int`. (This is still true in modern C for functions declared as shown above, i.e. without prototype.)

When eventually C language developed to the point where *prototype* function declarations were introduced, it was important to align the new declarations with legacy behavior of standard functions and with already compiled legacy libraries.

This is the reason why you will never see such types as `char` or `short` in argument lists of legacy function declarations. For the very same reason you won't see type `float` used there either.

---

This also means that if for some reason you have to provide a prototype declaration for some existing legacy function defined in K&R style, you have to remember to specify the *promoted* parameter types in the prototype. E.g. for the function defined as

```
int some_KandR_function(a, b, c)
char a;
short b;
float c;
{
}
```

the proper prototype prototype declaration is actually

```
int some_KandR_function(int a, int b, double c);
```

but not

```
int some_KandR_function(char a, short b, float c); // <- Incorrect!
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the standard functions that deal in characters do. I think the reason is partly historical (in some pre-standard versions of C, a function couldn't take a `char` or `unsigned char` argument, just like varargs arguments can't have character type) and partly for consistency across all such functions.

There are a few character-handling functions that *have* to use `int` in order to allow for the possibility of EOF, but `memchr` isn't one of them.

Comment: Did you really mean "EOL"?

Comment: No, it's `EOF`, a (necessarily negative, commonly -1) value which in-band signals an end of file. That's why e.g. `fgetc` returns `int`, or `isalnum` takes one: both work with `unsigned char` and `EOF`, the latter not being representable as an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types. On a specific implementation you don't know whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Except in rare systems (see Keith's note), the type `int` comprises all the values those three types can have.

Comment: On most systems. If `sizeof (int) == 1` (implying `CHAR_BIT >= 16`), then `int` may not be able to hold all values of type `unsigned char`. Such systems are rare.

Comment: @pmg That's why I completed "char, signed char and unsigned char" with EOF.

Answer (score 0):

C never passes arguments smaller than an int to a function. Defining a function argument as char or short is always promoted to an int and defining an unsigned char or unsigned short argument is always promoted to an unsigned int.
If the unsigned vs signed char were the issue, they would have used a short (I don't recall a single platform where a short is 1 byte long).
And of course using an int handles the unsigned vs signed char possibility as memchr is only comparing equality.

Comment: That is not true. If you open godbolt and change the type of the default function (square) from `int` to `char`, you can see that the assembly changes from copying a DWORD to a BYTE, following which there are two "move with sign extend" in order to fill extended registries from bytes, before performing the `imul`. Same story with `-O`, the `int` version self-multiplies `edi` as-is, while the `char` version performs a sign-extended copy of `dil` (the low 8 bits of `DI`) to `EAX`, which it self-multiplies.