# memset manual description: int type or constant byte?

Tags: c, types, memset, manual

I have a question regarding `memset` and its [manual's entry](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html). Here is what I can see in the manual for `memset`:

> ```
>    void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The  memset()  function  fills  the  first  n  bytes of the memory area
>          pointed to by s with the constant byte c.
>
> [...]

The manual says `with the constant byte c`, but `c` is an integer, whose size actually depends on several factors (compiler, architecture ...).
In the general case, `sizeof(int) > 1` (usually `4`).

**My question is**: Why isn't `c` a `char`, which always has a `sizeof` of `1` and thus corresponds to a byte ?
And then, what is the 'real' behavior of memset in border cases (undefined?) ?
By border cases, i mean for instance a case where `sizeof(int) = 4`, and `n=7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard has a better wording.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 7.24.6.1,

> The `memset` function copies the value of `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) into each of the first n characters of the object pointed to by `s`.

Comment: Why is it not specified as `char` in the first place?

Comment: I'm purely speculating but perhaps it's because casting down to a char is more explicit usually than casting down to an int. Again, purely speculating.

Comment: @taskinoor, if I remember correctly then a char as parameter is always converted to int and then passed as parameter value. So it seems it doesn't matter.

Comment: @taskinoor What'd be the advantage?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Are you talking about default argument promotion?

Comment: Yes, I am. Also, with stacks you can't push a char.

Comment: Got it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919735/why-does-memset-take-an-int-instead-of-a-char

Comment: Thanks, exactly the information I was looking for, the behavior of `memset` can be deduced once we know about this cast. Nice day to you sir :)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That was certainly true in the pre-prototype, pre-standard days, and I should think the parameter is now specified as an `int` for backwards compatibility reasons.