# How does memccpy handle large integer values?

Tags: c, c-standard-library

According to `man 3 memccpy` the `memccpy` function is defined as follows:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> void *memccpy(void *dest, const void *src, int c, size_t n);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `memccpy()` function copies no more than `n` bytes from memory area `src` to memory area `dest`, stopping when the character `c` is found.
>
> If the memory areas overlap, the results are undefined.

What confuses me is that `memccpy` copies `n` bytes and stops if ***character*** `c` is found. However, the function takes `int c` as an argument. So what happens if I call `memccpy` with the following value:

```
memccpy(&x, &y, 0xffffff76, 100);
```

Here the value to check is too big for `char`. Should this case work?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919735/why-does-memset-take-an-int-instead-of-a-char answer your question?

Comment: @KamilCuk no I don't see an explanation on how exactly this case is handled in code.

Comment: Some manuals mention that `c` is *converted* to `unsigned char`. So it is basically taking the value of `(unsigned char)c` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memccpy ,https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memccpy.html

Comment: At least one implementation (i.e., GNU) of `memccpy` calls `memchr` with the value passed. So, you'd want to ask "what does `memchr` do with the value you want to test".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memccpy()` is defined by POSIX.1-2001 ([IEEE Std 1003.1-2001](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/)), which states:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> void *memccpy(void *restrict s1, const void *restrict s2,
>        int c, size_t n);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `memccpy()` function shall copy bytes from memory area `s2` into `s1`, stopping after the first occurrence of byte `c` (**converted to an unsigned char**) is copied, or after n bytes are copied, whichever comes first. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

So there you go, a simple `unsigned char` conversion takes place:

```c
void *memccpy(void *restrict s1, const void *restrict s2, int c, size_t n) {
    unsigned char actual_c = (unsigned char)c;
    // ...
}
```

---

In fact, the most prominent C standard library implementations that I know do exactly this:

- [GNU libc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/memccpy.c;h=40ea81dcb606ef06bfbf61de279265b03a85d8e1;hb=HEAD#l31): passed to `memchr` which does `unsigned char c = (unsigned int)c_in;`
- [BSD libc](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/string/memccpy.c?view=markup#l41): `unsigned char uc = c;`
- [Bionic](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/master/libc/upstream-openbsd/lib/libc/string/memccpy.c#35) (Android): borrowed from BSD `unsigned char uc = c;`
- [musl libc](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/memccpy.c#n10): reassignment with cast `c = (unsigned char)c;`
- [uClibc](https://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/string/memccpy.c#n12): cast at comparison: `(((unsigned char)(*r1++ = *r2++)) != ((unsigned char) c))`

Answer (score 4):

> how exactly this case is handled in code

Just the value of the parameter is *converted* to a character:

```
void *memccpy(..., int param_c, ...) {
     unsigned char c = param_c;
```

In real life : https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/memccpy.c#L33 https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/memchr.c#L63 .

(On nowadays systems) `unsigned char` has 8 bits, `(unsigned char)(int)0xffffff76` just becomes `0x76`. The upper bits are just ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older function which is similar to `memset` in terms of the argument it accepts:

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

It is described in the C standard as follows:

> The `memset` function copies the value of `c` (**converted to an `unsigned char`**) into
> each of the first `n` characters of the object pointed to by `s`.

Both functions date back to at least 4.3 BSD, so it would make sense that they handle their arguments in a similar way.

So given your example, the value 0xffffff76 would be converted to the `unsigned char` value 0x76, and that would be the value it check for to stop.